# How can I add a message in an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to add my bot's message to an array directly after I send it

I've tried something like that :

```
task_chan.send('', {
embed: {
      color: task_colors[0x808080],
      title: 'Tache n°1',
      thumbnail: {
         url: 'https://...'
      },
      author: {
         name: 'Tache à prendre',
         icon_url: 'https://zupimages.net/up/20/12/xqsf.jpg'
      },
      fields:[{
         name: "Tache à faire :",
         value: "...",
      },{
         name: 'Avancement de la tache :',
         value: 'Non commencée'
      }]
      }
})
.then(tasks.push(bot.user.lastMessage))
```

`tasks` is defined using `var tasks = []`

when I execute this code, it sends the message correctly but it does not save it in the array, it is the one just before which is saved.

Comment: you need to pass `then` a function. try `.then( () => tasks.push(bot.user.lastMessage) )`

Comment: Thank you it perfectly works ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, `.then` requires a function as it's first argument. So what is happening is that `tasks.push(bot.user.lastMessage)` was trying to be executed as a parameter, and may have been failing silently, or maybe you missed the error message.

`.then( () => tasks.push(bot.user.lastMessage) )` passes an anonymous function to then which executes your task push.

`.then` also gives you access to the result of your asynchronous `.send` actions which may be useful to you. You can access it by giving the anonymous function a parameter:

```
.then( (res) => { 
  console.log(res)
  tasks.push(bot.user.lastMessage) 
})
```